# Let $R, P , Q$ be relations, prove that the following statement is tautology

Tags: logic

> Let $P, R, Q$ be relations. Prove that:
>
> $\exists x(R(x) \vee P(x)) \to (\forall y \neg R(y) \to (\exists xQ(x)
>  \to \forall x \neg P(x)))$ is a tautology.

How do I do so? please help.

Comment: Are you using a deductive system or can the proof be informal?

Comment: @GitGud well basiaclly I just need to show that it's a tautology,     I suppose it will be ok if you wont prove it but only show.

Comment: I'm looking for some context here. It's not clear to me what **exactly** you want. Are you familiar with rules like the ones shown [here](http://faculty.washington.edu/smcohen/120/Chapter6.pdf).

Comment: @GitGud Yes ofcourse...

Comment: I auggest you add to the question something like `I have to prove that, using a deductive system, ...` It would help if you'd mention what the inference rules are.

Comment: @GitGud kinda misunderstood it, i dont need to prove it with deductice system, But with predicate Calculus.

Comment: Note that it's rather a formula or a statement, not a sentence.

Comment: @Gigili: What? It is a sentence.

Comment: @ChrisEagle: I've never heard of it in the context of logic.

Comment: @user1798362: That's no way of communicating with people who are spending time on helping you.

Comment: I just need a simple explenation for the statements which says why it's a tautology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a tautology. Consider a universe with one single object such that the object satisfies $P$ and it doesn't satisfy $R$. For simplicity let $Q$ mean the same as $P$.

Then it is true that $\exists x(R(x) \lor P(x))$. It is also true that $\forall y \neg R(y)$. Furthermore it is true that $\exists xQ(x)$. However it is false that $\forall x \neg P(x)$ because of our initial hypothesis.

Comment: yep, it's a question from an exam, and i got to the same conclusion, probably the proffesor was "not smart", -> thanks

Comment: @user1798362 No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Relations of arity 1 (that is the relations that take only one argument) are just subsets of the universe. Therefore, your formula can be translated into

$$(R \cup P \neq \varnothing) \to (R = \varnothing \to (Q \neq \varnothing \to P = \varnothing))$$

and then simplified into

$$(R \neq \varnothing \lor P \neq \varnothing) \to (R = \varnothing \to (Q \neq \varnothing \to P = \varnothing)),$$

and further into

$$(r \lor p) \to (\neg r \to (q \to \neg p)),$$

where $r := (R \neq \varnothing)$, etc. Now, let's set $\neg r$, $p$ and $q$, then $$(0\lor 1) \to (1 \to (1 \to 0)) = 1 \to (1 \to 0) = 1 \to 0 = 0,$$

which shows that your formula is not a tautology. To generate appropiate example, we set $U = \{\bullet\}$ and $R = \varnothing, P = U, Q = U$. Now we evaluate

$$\exists x_1(R(x_1) \vee P(x_1)) \to (\forall y_2 \neg R(y_2) \to (\exists x_3Q(x_3)
 \to \neg \exists x_4 P(x_4))) $$

by setting $x_1 = \bullet$, $x_3 = \bullet$ and $x_4 = \bullet$ (observe that I have changed $\forall x \neg P(x)$ to $\neg \exists x_4 P(x_4)$, so that I can put some value there). What we get is

$$(R(\bullet) \vee P(\bullet)) \to (\forall y_2 \neg R(y_2) \to (Q(\bullet)
 \to \neg P(\bullet))). $$

Now, $\forall y_2 \neg R(y_2)$ is true, so we get exactly the same expression as before, i.e. your formula is false in this case.

---

What would make it a tautology is, for example, $\land$ in the beginning

$$\exists x_1(R(x_1) \land P(x_1)) \to (\forall y_2 \neg R(y_2) \to (\exists x_3Q(x_3)
 \to \forall x_4 \neg P(x_4))) $$

which could be more easily seen with

$$(R \cap P \neq \varnothing) \to (R = \varnothing \to (Q \neq \varnothing \to P = \varnothing)).$$

If we substitute $\alpha := (Q \neq \varnothing \to P = \varnothing)$, that is

$$(R \cap P \neq \varnothing) \to (R = \varnothing \to \alpha),$$

then we can observe that $\alpha$ does not matter, because $(R \cap P \neq \varnothing)$ implies $R \neq \varnothing$. To do it more formally, consider two cases:

- $R = \varnothing$, then the left side of the top-most implication is false, hence all is true.
- $R \neq \varnothing$, then the left side of the $R = \varnothing \to \alpha$ is false, so the right side of the top-most implication is true, hence, the expression is true.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing the truth table with $2^3$ possible valuations, it turns out there are four columns with the value $0$ which means the statement is not a tautology.